# How does nested child directive root element working at the same level of the parent's directive root element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello I’m currently in a situation which I can’t find the solution anywhere,

I would like to know how and if it’s possible to replace a directives root element’s content with one declared from a nested (child) directive.

```
<div id=”main”>
  <nav>
     <main-directive></main-directive>
  </nav>
</div>

//mainDirective’s template
<div id=”mainDir>
  <p>Hello World </p>
  <child-directive></child-Directive>
</div>

//childDirective’s template
<div id=”childDir”>
  <p>I conquered the world</p>
</div>
```

What I’m actually trying to do is, when I apply an ng-click from the mainDirective then the childDirective appears over the mainDirective replacing the position of the div where its located so in this case
 will be replaced with the root element of the childDirective being 
On a side note, when I click a back button, the childDirective hides and the parent's root element is shown again.

->mainDirective->onClick()->childDirective ->OnBackClick() ->mainDirective

an example where this occurs is from here and I am implementing something similar but I do not get the same results as in this source code and after breaking it all down I don’t see what I have wrong.

https://github.com/wuxiaoying/angular-multilevelpushmenu
I try at a much simpler level 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBSMCksf1znwG8SEK5Bv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can actually use simple JavaScript command:

```
//mainDirective’s template
<div id=”mainDir>
  <p>Hello World </p>
  <div id="childcontent"></div> 
// This is the new DIV where the Content of the childDir div will be after clicking the button.
</div>

//childDirective’s template
<div id=”childDir”>
  <p>I conquered the world</p>
</div>
```

So make a function which replaces the content from the div childcontent which the content of the childDir

```
function replacecontent()
{
    document.getElementById('childcontent').innerHTML = document.getElementById('childDir').innerHTML;
}
```

Greetings